# How to get Value [Object [Object] ] in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I try to get value structure like this.

**JSON Example :**

```
    [
      {
        "operationalVehicleExtendDetails": [
          {
            "date_Book": "2018-11-14T00:00:00+07:00",
            "bookingVehicleProces": null
          },
          {
            "date_Book": "2018-11-15T00:00:00+07:00",
            "bookingVehicleProces": null
          },
        ],
        "id": 1,
        "brand": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Toyota"
        },
        "type": "Avanza (sample)",
        "chassisNumber": "0101010101",
        "machineNumber": "1111111111",
        "bpkbNumber": "0000000000",
        "licenseNumber": "D 54 MPE",
        "color": "Black",
        "year": 2013,
        "annualTax": "2019-11-14T16:17:00.9047974",
        "annual5Tax": "2023-11-14T16:17:00.9050494",
        "kirValidityPeriod": "2020-11-14T16:17:00.9045803",
        "isActive": true
      }
    ]
```

And this is my getDataFunction

```
 public AllDasboards: Array<any> = [];

 public getDataSem() {
    this.listvehicleService.getAllDashboard().subscribe(data => {
      this.AllDasboards = [];
      for(let key in data){
        this.AllDasboards.push({
          "brand": data[key].brand.name,
          "date_book": data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails.book_date
        })
        for (let index in data.operationalVehicleExtendDetails) {
          this.AllDasboards.push({
            "book_date": data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails[index].book_date,
            "bookingvehicleproses": data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails[index].bookingVehicleProces
          });
        }
      }
      console.log(this.AllDasboards);
    })
  }
```

This is my output what i get from my code:
[image]
**Output console log data :**
[image]
The problem is i cannot get the value operationalVehicleExtendDetails[],and
i only get the value brand and another out of "operationalVehicleExtendDetails"[], any solution to solve my problem? please help :)

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, provide detailed example of what you want.

Comment: I already add the detailed @Justcode

Comment: Please add our expect output.

Comment: my output in UI?

Comment: No what kind of output you want, add expected output you want.

Comment: in JSON Example sir

Comment: Can you do `console.log(data)` before pushing to AllDashboards? and show us the output

Comment: ok wait @JavascriptLover-SKT

Comment: You are doing wrong in manipulating _operationalVehicleExtendDetails_ array.

Comment: already added sir @JavascriptLover-SKT

Comment: so the solution sir? @Arcteezy

Comment: `"date_book": data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails[index].book_date ` should be inside this  `for (let index in data.operationalVehicleExtendDetails)  ` as its an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, this will work :

```
public getDataSem() {
  this.listvehicleService.getAllDashboard().subscribe(data => {
    this.AllDasboards = [];
    for(let key in data){
      // Changes ==>
      var tempBookDatesArray = []
      for (let index in data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails) {
        tempBookDatesArray.push(data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails[index].date_Book);
      }
      this.AllDasboards.push({
        "brand": data[key].brand.name,
        "date_book": tempBookDatesArray
      })
      // <==
    }
    console.log(this.AllDasboards);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for..in` is to loop through the properties of an object not an array. You can find the reference for `for..in` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

so you should use normal `for` to access the elements

```
for (let key in data) {
  this.AllDasboards.push({
    "brand": data[key].brand.name
  })
  for (let index = 0 index < data.operationalVehicleExtendDetails.length; index++) {
    this.AllDasboards.push({
      "book_date": data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails[index].book_date,
      "bookingvehicleproses": data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails[index].bookingVehicleProces
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your second for loop to:

```
for (let index in data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails) {
      this.AllDasboards.push({
        "book_date": data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails[index].date_Book,
        "bookingvehicleproses": data[key].operationalVehicleExtendDetails[index].bookingVehicleProces
      });
    }
```